# $(window).load(function() event not firing on Safari Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to run some JQuery code after the page completes loading but although it's working on desktop browsers it's not firing the event on Safari Mobile.

This is the code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   //Alert('event was fired');
});
```

I'm also using JQuery Mobile ... don't know if it has something to do with the problem.

Comment: Look at the events jQM offers: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Comment: @PhillPafford Will any of the page events that jQM offers wait for all assets to load before firing?

Comment: @Jasper Good question, not sure at the moment

Comment: Hmm...we it cannot be done? No event like that on JQM

Comment: @Satch3000 Could you post more code? It would be helpful to see where in your document you are running the code you have posted so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will only fire on the initial page load, as all subsequent page transitions are AJAX based and will not fire a document ready or window load event.

The closest match, given your requirements is the `pagechange` event, provided by JQM. This fires after page has been loaded into the DOM and the transition animation has completed.

```
$(document).live('pagechange',function(){
  //your logic
});
```